# "The same table " LEFT JOINE ON " the same commen field " in MS-Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access, outer-join, ms-access-2016

I have something like this

Employe (Emp_ID , Emp_Name)
SecurityGuards (MainEmp_ID , AlternativeEmp_ID ).           // Security guards are considered as Employees

My sql query as follows

```
  Select Employe.Emp_Name 
  From ( Employe
  LEFT JOIN ON SecurityGuards ON SecurityGuards.MainEmp_ID = Employe.Emp_ID)
  LEFT JOIN ON SecurityGuards ON SecurityGuards.AlternativeEmp_ID = Employe.Emp_ID
```

Now i want the query to show Both main and alternative Guards by names not IDs but it just gives me error saying "join expression is not supported "
although removing the second LEFT Join works fine .
Im using MS-Access 2016

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must join `SecurityGuards` to 2 copies of `Employee` to get the 2 names:

```
SELECT e1.Emp_Name AS MainName, e2.Emp_Name AS AlternativeName
FROM (SecurityGuards AS s 
LEFT JOIN Employee AS e1 ON e1.Emp_ID = s.MainEmp_ID)
LEFT JOIN Employee AS e2 ON e2.Emp_ID = s.AlternativeEmp_ID
```

Comment: By addint a copy of employees u mean to make a new Employee table with the same data ?

Comment: No, nothing like that. The same table Employee is used twice in the query with 2 different aliases e1 and e2 because you must get 2 values from Employee for every row of SecurityGuards for the 2 names.

Comment: Didnt realise that e1 and e2 in the select statement are aliased in the LEFT Join statement ,   Thanks Everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results in one row, you can use table aliases and two `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
select  . . .
from (Employe as E left join
      SecurityGuards as sgm
      ON sgm.MainEmp_ID = e.Emp_ID
     ) left join
     SecurityGuards as sga
     ON sga.AlternativeEmp_ID = e.Emp_ID;
```

If you just want employees that are in either column, use `EXISTS`:

```
select e.*
from employe as e
where exists (select 1
              from SecurityGuards as sg
              where e.Emp_ID in (sg.MainEmp_ID, sg.AlternativeEmp_ID
             );
```

Comment: It seems not to be working for me . Dunno if im doing somthing wrong or what but applying @Gordon Method makes error in the select statement above as it cont relate Emp_ID to the Emp_Name !

Comment: @GeboA . . . There is no "relat[ing] EMP_ID to EMP_Name" in this query.